# MySQL workbench permission denied for files in media drives under "Other Locations" of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mysql, ubuntu-22.04, mysql-workbench

I've freshly installed MySQL workbench in a new Ubuntu system (**Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**) through Ubuntu Software center and all installations and database connections are configured smoothly.

But when I try to open a sql file saved inside Other ***Locations -> D*** drive of ubuntu system, the workbench giving permission denied error as attached below.

[image]
[image]

Please suggest the workaround to open sql files from media drives.

Comment: Does this also happen for other programs, or only for MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @u1686_grawity this issue observing only only in workbench. Text editor, netbeans, android studio etc are allowing to open files/project from media drives without any issue.

Comment: How did you install Workbench – was it from `apt` or Snap or Flatpak or a tarball in ~/downloads?

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, i was installed through Ubuntu Software Center. That is the default GUI available in Ubuntu OS to manage software programs. I believe, internally Ubuntu Software is working with the help of snap.

Comment: If it's Snap, do you see any AppArmor denial messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: Yes, apparmor gives "DENIED" flag. `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench-community" name="/media/" pid=11570 comm="pool-mysql-work" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0`

Comment: @mpsbhat - You should [edit] your question instead of using unformatted commentary to clarify your  
 question. At face value it appears the folder does not have the correct permissions to allow the user who started the process to access the folder in question.

Comment: @Ramhound Obviously the "access denied" error is must be due to the uncorrect permission but my question is what is the solution or what is the possible setps to enable the permission. I feel it is well understandable in my OP.

Comment: @mpsbhat - You provided details in a comment that should be in the question. It’s entirely up to you if you want to provide that information in the body of your question. You should first identify which user the process is running as and then the owner of the folder in question (and provide that information as an edit to your question)

Comment: As i mentioned in my post, i installed mysql workbench through ubuntu software center and I opening the workbench program by clicking on the icon which is added in app lists after installation. I believe ubuntu system is using root user itself for all these steps behind the scene. I was used the same method earlier to instal workbench in old Ubuntu 14.04 system and there no such permission issues observed but observing in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as well as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS